# ClickHouse db connect

Tags: python, clickhouse

I have a problem connecting my database to ClickHouse. i use python:

Code Error: 210
Can you help me with this question?

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client

# Установка параметров подключения к базе данных ClickHouse
host = 'localhost'
port = 8123  # Порт по умолчанию для ClickHouse
user = ''
password = ''
database = 'myBase'

# Создание клиента ClickHouse
client = Client(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)

# Пример выполнения запроса к базе данных
query = 'SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 10'
result = client.execute(query)

# Вывод результатов запроса
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Please provide the whole error message

Comment: Removed the mysql tag as I see no relevance to it. Please only add it back if you can explain why mysql knowledge is needed for answering this question!

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the clickhouse-driver source code https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver

It looks like it uses the ClickHouse Native TCP protocol, not HTTP/HTTPS. ClickHouse Native port (unencrypted) runs on port 9000 by default, not 8123 (HTTP Port unencrypted)

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/sre/network-ports